# Pass complex query result as a parameter in PL SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor

My goal is to execute a query inside a procedure and then pass the result to another procedure that processes data and prints some html tables.

```
type utentiCursorType IS REF CURSOR; /*in a separate package*/

procedure GeneraRisultatiClienti(
IdSessione integer,
Nome varchar2,
Cognome varchar2,
Giorno varchar2,
Mese varchar2,
Anno varchar2,
Via varchar2,
Civico varchar2,
CapZip varchar2,
Citta varchar2,
Stato varchar2,
Telefono varchar2,
Mobile varchar2 default '',
Email varchar2,
Username varchar2
 ) is
clienti_cur utentiCursorType;
begin
open clienti_cur for
  select u.id, u.nome, u.cognome, u.username
  from Utenti u, Clienti c
  where u.id = c.id_Utente
  and (Nome is null or u.nome = Nome ) 
  and (Cognome is null or u.cognome = Cognome)
  and (DataDiNascita is null or u.data_di_nascita = DataDiNascita)
  and (Via is null or u.via = Via)
  and (Civico is null or u.civico = Civico)
  and (CapZip is null or u.cap_zip = CapZip)
  and (Citta is null or u.citta = Citta)
  and (Stato is null or u.stato = Stato)
  and (Telefono is null or u.telefono = Telefono)
  and (Mobile is null or u.mobile = Mobile)
  and (Email is null or u.email = Email)
  and (Username is null or u.username = Username);

pkgruppo1.VisualizzaClienti(IdSessione, clienti_cur);

end GeneraRisultatiClienti;

procedure VisualizzaClienti(IdSessione integer, risultati in utentiCursorType) is

/*riga Risultati%ROWTYPE;*/

begin

    modGUI.ApriPagina('Risultati', IdSessione);
    pkgruppo1.CreaMenuGruppo1(IdSessione);

    modGUI.ApriTabella;

    modGUI.ApriRigaTabella;
    modGUI.IntestazioneTabella('Nome');
    modGUI.IntestazioneTabella('Cognome');
    modGUI.IntestazioneTabella('Username');
    modGUI.ChiudiRigaTabella;

    for riga in risultati
    loop

        modGUI.ApriRigaTabellaConBottoni('proceduraGestioneAzione');

        modGUI.PassaParametro('IdRecord', riga.id);
        modGUI.ElementoTabella(riga.nome);
        modGUI.ElementoTabella(riga.cognome);
        modGUI.ElementoTabella(riga.username);

        modGUI.ChiudiRigaTabellaConBottoni('azDettagli', 'azModifica', 'azElimina');
    modGUI.ChiudiTabella;

    modGUI.ChiudiPagina;

    end loop;*/

end VisualizzaClienti;
```

As you can see i want to use a general cursor type because the query result is not always the same. 
Obviously "for riga in risultati" does not work.
How can i process that cursor without using things like fetch  into ?

Thanks

Comment: What is wrong with FETCH INTO?  "A cursor FOR loop implicitly declares its loop index as a %ROWTYPE record, opens a cursor, repeatedly fetches rows of values from the result set into fields in the record, and closes the cursor when all rows have been processed. When the cursor FOR loop is entered, the cursor name cannot belong to a cursor already opened by an OPEN statement or enclosing cursor FOR loop."

Comment: If your queries have different rowtype see "Oracle - select a specific column from a ref cursor" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10321571/oracle-select-a-specific-column-from-a-ref-cursor

Comment: Your statement: _"How can i process that cursor without using things like fetch into ?"_ makes no sense. Why you don't want to use `fetch into` ? I recommend reading the fine manual: [Fetching Data with Cursor Variables](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/static.htm#LNPLS581).

Comment: The query makes a join between two tables. So how can i use FETCH INTO without using a variable of type <table>%ROWTYPE? Is there a way to store in a cursor such a complex result?

Answer (score 0):

Use `ref_cursor` to hand recordsets araound ...
Search web for samples like https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/using-ref-cursors-to-return-recordsets